# Get Method in Laravel's Route Class?

Tags: class, methods, laravel-4, get, laravel-routing

I wanted to have a look at the defined methods of Route class in Laravel. The first method we commonly use is get. Route::get('/', function() {});

But I am unable to find the get method in documentation. Anyone can share the link for the same ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read everything about routing in much detail from their source code.

Routing class path will be:
    X:\wamp\www\YOURLARAVELFOLDER\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php

Plus, you can find some in the documentation also:
    http://laravel.com/docs/routing

The methods that you can use with Route is an array: array('GET', 'HEAD', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS');

Answer (score 0):

The API of Laravel can be found on [GitHub](http://github.com/laravel/framework) as well as via the [4.2 API browser](http://laravel.com/api/4.2/).

The methods you are looking for are on [`Illuminate\Routing\Router`](http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Routing/Router.html).